# Kohana 3.3 config files

Tags: php, kohana

Respective All!

How can I store Kohana configuration files (email, auth, pagination)
in MySQL database?

Any help would be very appreciated.

After some exercises I solved this.

Step 1: Create table (code from Kohana source

```
/modules/database/classes/Kohana/Config/Database\Writer.php`)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS config (
   group_name varchar(128) NOT NULL,
   config_key varchar(128) NOT NULL,
   config_value text,
   PRIMARY KEY (group_name,config_key)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Step 2: Put in bootstrap (I added after modules section):

```
Database::instance();
Kohana::$config->attach(new Kohana_Config_Database, FALSE);
```

Step 3: Use standard method to put serializable values into the table

```
Kohana::$config->_write_config('mymodule','options','Hard_to_solve')
```

Step 4: Use standard way to get it back

```
Kohana::$config->load('mymodule')->get('options')
```

Comment: out of curiosity, where do you plan on storing the credentials for the database?

Comment: The only config I want to keep in Kohana filesystem is application/config/database.php. Sorry for inconvenience!

Comment: I heard about Kohana_Config_Database_Reader and Kohana_Config_Database_Writer, but I don't know how to write code for these classes...

Comment: Just created a table config: `CREATE TABLE config (
 group_name varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 config_key varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
 config_value varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`. Also added to bootstrap after modules section:`Database::instance();
Kohana::$config->attach(new Config_Database, FALSE);` But when I tried to execute a code: `Kohana::$config->load('lbeauty');` I've got an error :`unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 4 bytes`. What is it? And how to struggle?

Comment: Uhhh.. Instead of direct inserts into the table config one should use  `Kohana::config$->_write_config($group,$key, $value)` to keep values serializable in the database

Comment: This may not be the best idea. It's going to hit your database a lot for stuff that needn't be in the database.

Answer (score 0):

What you are clearly describing is simply accessing a database. If there are some configuration options you want to store in a database so that your app or web app can retrieve them, you simply need to look at how Kohana accesses databases. Start by looking in the application/bootstrap.php and uncomment the database module (also uncomment userguide). You'll then need to copy the modules/database/config/database.php to your config folder and setup the access. If you uncommented the userguide, just go to http://yourdomain.com/guide (replace "yourdomain" with your actual domain name) and there is a whole description of how to setup kohana for database access all the way through to making queries. Have fun!